# I have trouble using the try-catch method for a exception in java

Tags: java, oop, try-catch

I do not know how to successfully try and catch the exception. As you can see I already started the try-catch statement but do not know how to finish it. I get the error " tractorException.java:83: error: unreported exception tractorException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         setVehicleID(0); "

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class tractorException extends Exception {
    protected int VehicleID; 

    public int setVehicleID(int VehicleID) throws tractorException {
        if (VehicleID <= 0 || VehicleID > 100000) {
            throw new tractorException();
        } else {
            this.VehicleID = VehicleID;
             return this.VehicleID;
        }
    }

    public int getVehicleID() {
        return this.VehicleID;
    }

    tractorException() {
        setVehicleID(0);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {             
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A class that infinitely throws exceptions?

Comment: Yes I am trying to achieve a class that only throws exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Change your `main` method to:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
      try {
         throw new tractorException(); // infinite loop ensues
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // this catch doesn't matter
      }
}
```

The infinite loop occurs because `tractorException`'s constructor calls `setVehicleID(0)`, which in turn calls `throw new tractorException()`, which, as you guessed, calls `setVehicleID(0)` ... to infinity and beyond.

Comment: To make the program compile you also have to declare that the constructor  `throws tractorException`.

Comment: I don't think the program will compile if you do make it throw a `tractorException`, I think (but I'm not sure) the java compiler is smart enough to tell that an infinite loop will occur.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Oh wow, you'd think it'd be smart enough to at least issue a warning.

Answer (score 0):

A function that throws exception must be caught or declared to be thrown.  The issue you have with your code is in the line `setVehicleID(0);` as stated in the error log you posted.

Since `setVehicleID()` method throws exception, any time you call this function, it must be caught or re-throw.  To fix your error, you need to surround this call with try catch:

```
  tractorException()
  {
     try{
       setVehicleID(0);
     }
     catch( tractorException e ) {
       // Do something with error
     }
  }
```

Comment: Also want to point out setVehicleID(0) will generate an exception with value pass in as 0, thus will invoke the constructor, which will invoke setVehicleID(0).. etc.. etc.. basically a infinite loop

Comment: You want to update the tractorException() of you code to have the try-catch block as shown above.  This will resolve the compiling issue you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

try enter this

you cannot call Directly setVehicleID method because it is risky Method

```
tractorException() {
try{
    setVehicleID(0);
}catch(Exception e){

}
}
```